# What paper pauper cards on not legal in MTGO

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

I am trying to collect most cards relevant to pauper. Because MTGO pauper is more popular than paper pauper, and because it is so easily available electronically, it is easy to find data and analysis on the most frequently used cards in pauper. I did this.

The problem is that there are some cards (most notably Hymn to Tourach and High Tide) not available on MTGO but are essential paper pauper commons. Other popular pauper cards include Goblin Grenade, Desert, Pyrotechnics, and Sinkhole. So they are easy to miss when starting a paper pauper collection, though I suppose you'd eventually come across them in pauper tournaments.

The question:

Is there a list maintained of cards printed at common for paper, but not MTGO? If so, please provide link. If there is no such list but it turns out to be very few cards, then the answer should contain the list of cards.

Comment: Joe, in case you don't see the meta post. I closed/merged this question by mistake.  Please ask it again if you're still looking for answers.  Sorry about this!